# Do I have to use jquery mobile with phonegap to make a hybird app

Tags: django, cordova, jquery-mobile, hybrid-mobile-app

I have developed a web app using html, css, jquery and django, and has made it compatible for the screen in mobile devices. But now I want to make it a hybrid app for android/ios and users can install it for extra features. Googled and found phonegap to be a perfect solution. On further searching for the tutorial, most of the tutorial are using jquery mobile for the purpose. My question is, do I need to use jquery mobile to develop a phonegap hybrid app?

Comment: You shouldn't need jquery mobile for phonegap. Depending on the nature of your app you can also consider ionic framework. Due to the heavy use of angular with that, it is a perfect match for django rest framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, its not needed, jQuery, without mobile version, its perfectly capable of working with Cordova (I have also made several professional projects with it).

The only limitation is with some touch events, like swipe or pinch to zoom, in what you are going to need another library, like hammerjs